# unable to update the snapshot version of aws mysql rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

AWS MYSQL RDS have deprecated the 5.6.41 version. So, I updated the database version and changed the version to 5.7.33 but when I do the server less automation I get the error as

```
An error occurred: MySqlRDSInstance - Cannot find version 5.6.41 for mysql (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: dd3fff83-82c8-47ef-a976-828beea1614f; Proxy: null).
```

I use this commands in codebuild to craete and deploy the different environments

```
version: 0.1
  phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm install -g serverless@2.7.0
  build:
    commands:
      - serverless create_domain --companyCode $COMPANY_CODE --rootDomain mydomain.com
      - serverless deploy --companyCode $COMPANY_CODE --rootDomain mydomain.com
```

I can see the 5.6.41 version in snapshots, but am unable to upgrade the snapshot version, so is there any solution to upgrade the snapshot or can I delete the snapshot if I delete is there any issue?

Edit- I have updated the version in all available areas. The only place i see the older version is in snapshots. Not sure if I should edit this. any insights on fixing the error could be helpfull

Comment: Please clarify how are you updating your snapshot, and what is the meaning of `when I do the server less automation `

Comment: updated my question please check now